# Setting Found/Open Workbook(s)

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem:** I can't set a found/open workbook

**Code:** Below is my code.  My error is on line `Set wkbTemp = wkbTempStr` error `Type Mismatch`.

I have tried a few variations, done some searching but turning up blanks.. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Test_wkb()

    Dim wbcount As Integer
    wbcount = Workbooks.Count

    For i = 1 To wbcount
        wkb = Workbooks(i).Path & "\" & Workbooks(i).Name
    Debug.Print wkb
    Next

    Dim wkbTempStr As String
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim wksTemp As Worksheet

    wkbTempStr = "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\Consolidate Macro.xlsm"

    Set wkbTemp = wkbTempStr
    Set wksTemp = wkbTemp.Sheets("Pay")

    'just seeing if code works below
    wksTemp.Range("I18") = "This works"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Open/Closed Workbook

When referring to an open Workbook, you have to use its name i.e. file name e.g. "`Consolidate Macro.xlsm`". If it isn't open, you will have to use the full path to **open** it, if it isn't in the current directory (best is always).

### The Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test_wkb()

    Dim wkb As String
    Dim wbcount As Long
    Dim i As Long

    wbcount = Workbooks.Count

    For i = 1 To wbcount
        wkb = Workbooks(i).Path & "\" & Workbooks(i).Name
        Debug.Print wkb
    Next

    Dim wkbTempStr As String
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim wksTemp As Worksheet

    wkbTempStr = "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\Consolidate Macro.xlsm"

    ' If you want to suppress the message alerting that the workbook is already 
    ' open, uncomment the two "Application ..." lines.
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(wkbTempStr)
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set wksTemp = wkbTemp.Sheets("Pay")

    'just seeing if code works below
    wksTemp.Range("I18") = "This works"

End Sub
```

Using the filename (`Workbook.Name`), you can loop through the open workbooks and check if it is open. If it isn't, then use the path to open it.

Comment: Thanks mate. I was on the right track, just needed `Workbooks.Open(wkbTempStr)
`. And yes, the file is already open. I will include the suppress `display.alerts`.